# How to get individual results of each test step through robotium without app getting closed

Tags: automated-tests, robotium

I am automating a mobile app through robotium.

In my application I read the test steps through excel eg. enter username, enter password etc and want to execute the particular test through robotium.

Get the result after executing test and write the result in excel(pass/fail) based on whether the step went through successfully or not.

Currently I have tried to make all test steps like enterusername, enterpassword as separate methods in my robotium class so that I can get result for each test step.

However once my first test step is finished(enterusername) robotium closes the app as it executes **solo.finishOpenActivities()** in **teardown**.

I tried commenting the **finishOpenActivities** however my 2nd test hung and when I tried to execute without teardown still it closed the app(seems like its been done implicitly in api).

Any way I can execute all my test steps sequencially without the app closing, would executing through test suite be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please rename `setUp()` method to any other name , e.g `startTest()`

From your 1st test method call `startTest()` and write logic in that way to write the result in excel.

Make sure to comment out `tearDown()` or rename it to something else.

**Explanation:**
Here we are using Junit3. So setUp() is going to be executed before each test method and tearDown() after each test method. So if you rename these methods and manually call these from your test methods depending upon the situation on when you want to launch the app and when to exit, app launching and exit is not going to be handled by Junit.

**Possibility:**
In your case as setUp() is still present , so Junit tries to launch the application activity which is not exited, so its hanging up.